# Windows Forms WebBrowser Control and AJAX

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

Right now i am calling my function on webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted. It doesn't run correctly. However when i press button2 and call the very same func it does. It seems like my code needs some time for JavaScript and Ajax to run. When event should i call my code from? i dont want to click a button every time?

Comment: Please clarify...which code, and where is it running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DocumentCompleted and check the URI for the AJAX request.

Comment: @John Saunders: yes but its very annoying that there are variant request. I dont know why some pages want 2 while other only needs 1. Most of the time its 2 so i'll try to figure out why some want 1 or find a workaround like a timeout for cases with one req (The uris dont help).